# RSA and Elgamal

Tags: cryptography

I'm working on Java cryptography. I found RSA/ECB/[somePadding] is not secure. Which modes can be used for RSA and Elgamal respectively? I want to implement both and analyze the performance.

Comment: First, read through and understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation. Then come back here and [edit] your question to show us what you have learned.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelKjörling you need to show some research effort

Comment: Furthermore, you don't want to use an API that would let you use something like ECB. If the API lets you do that, they don't care about security, only about marking feature checkboxes. You want to use an API that let cryptographers make choices about cryptography and lets you use something safe that you can't use incorrectly. This means libsodium or something very much like it.

Comment: Prior commentors, are you trying to imply that RSA should be used in CBC mode? Surely not? Or have I missed something? I feel like you didn't read the question properly or just blatantly don't understand it?  RSA isn't really used in any block cipher mode but if you had to name it, it would be ECB, that is why the Java Crypto API has named it such.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you have read, and the comments you received on your question, RSA in any "mode" other than ECB is **a terrible idea in all situations**.  If you need private key cryptography, and you need to encrypt more than ~240 bytes of data, then hybrid encryption is the way to go.  Never use RSA as a block cipher.

The reason I quoted "mode" above is because RSA doesn't use a cipher mode, purely because RSA is not a block cipher.  I think the reason you are confused, and the reason prior commentors are confused, is because the Java Crypto API expects the second value if you also want to define padding, and ECB is the only one that makes sense.  You can also use `None` I believe.

Remember this is specific to RSA.  RSA in "ECB mode" is **good**.  RSA in any other "mode" is **bad**.  Symmetric encryption in ECB mode is **bad**.

TL;DR: What you are doing is secure.  That one specific part.  I can't speak for any other parts of your project.